# Combining 2 functions

Tags: python, function

I am trying to combine two functions because A) I think I can and B) I think I should.  When I use the functions separately the script works fine.  When I combine them the "new" variable is an empty string vice what it should be.  Any help would be appreciated.  If you need the full script that could be arranged.

Function A:

```
def strip_domain_name(x):
    global ns
    l = x.find('@')
    ns = x[0:l]
```

Function B:

```
def encode_user_name(x,y):
    global new
    for a in x:
        if a in y:
            new = new + y.get(a)
```

Function A+B:

```
def combined_above_script(x,y,z):
    global ns
    global new  
    l = x.find('@')
    ns = x[0:l] 
    for a in y:
        if a in z:                  
            new = new + z.get(a)
```

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do, with some modifications based on blender's suggestion.  In the end if I print aa it should result in '0000000'.  Which is not the case.

```
aa = ''
bb = ''
encode = {'a':'0'}

def strip_and_encode(x,y,z):
aa = '' 
bb = x[0:x.find('@')]   

for a in y:
    if a in z:                  
        aa += z.get(a)

s='aaaaaaa@aaa'
strip_and_encode(s,bb,encode)
print(aa)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?  It looks like function_1 just returns the portion of a string (?) up to the first "@" sign.  function_2 looks like it returns the intersection of x and y.  In your combined script, I can't tell what the function_1 portion and the function_2 portion have to do with each other.  And why the globals?   And it's probably not a great idea to name a variable "new", because that is a keyword.

Comment: @Chris Curvey: 'new' isn't a Python keyword.

Comment: Your functions should probably return something.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go easy with the globals:

```
def script(x, y, z):
  new = ''
  ns = x[:x.find('@')]

  for a in y:
    if a in z:                  
      new += z.get(a)
```

Comment: Given the overuse of globals in the original question, the poster probably needs to throw a `return new` in there.

Comment: I'd also make `script()` a bit more descriptive ;)

Comment: Updated to reflect suggestions.